# Is ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED a sticky broadcast?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcast, boot

The [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) do not say one way or the other, but I can't imagine why you wouldn't let that stick.

My application goes into a paused mode when the SD card is not present- however if the user launches my application before the system is done booting, it goes into pause mode. So I'd like it to detect if the system has yet to finish booting and wait a few seconds accordingly.

But it becomes a moot point if your application has to already be running to hear ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED broadcasts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I can't imagine why you wouldn't let that stick.

That being said, according to the source code, it is not sticky.

> however if the user launches my application before the system is done booting, it goes into pause mode

How is that possible?

> But it becomes a moot point if your application has to already be running to hear ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED broadcasts.

No, it does not. In fact, the *only* way to get `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcasts is via a manifest-registered `BroadcastReceiver`, specifically because you cannot assume that any of your code will be executing at the time of the broadcast.

Comment: How is what possible- paused mode or launching the app before it's done booting? "Paused" just means an activity warning the user the app cannot continue without the SD card. "pre-boot launching" happens when running a kiosk version of my app that captures HOME intents.

Comment: And your last paragraph explains exactly why I wish the broadcast was sticky - so that I can verify the system has finished booting regardless of what point my application is launched.

Comment: @CommonsWare do you have a link to google docs for
"broadcasts is via a manifest-registered BroadcastReceiver"?
I actually want to set it programmatically with something like registerReceiver(mBootCompleted, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED));  Is there no possible way to do that and to remove the intent filter as well?

Comment: @MikeIsrael: "Is there no possible way to do that" -- by the time you call `registerReceiver()`, the boot will already have happened, and so the point is moot. "and to remove the intent filter as well" -- if you don't have an `IntentFilter`, you will receive no broadcasts.